# How can I blank the screen for 2 seconds (configurable) between playing a sequence of 360-degree videos in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written a C# script in Unity to play a sequence of 360-degree videos of one-min duration each. The script works as expected, thanks to the support received on stackoverflow. I would now like to add a delimiter of a few seconds between each video playback, something like a blank screen which would help differentiate between the beginning and end of each video.

I tried using a GameObject with an Image on a Canvas and then setting it active after each video is played. However, it does not work as expected.

```
private GameObject gameobject;
gameobject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Delimiter");
gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

Comment: Could you add a complete code example and explain a bit further what you mean by `it does not work` please?

Comment: Have you looked at coroutines?

Comment: Did you try disabling the used camera object?

Comment: I tried disabling the used camera object but it did not help.                                                          

//gameobject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
//gameObject.SetActive(false);
//gameObject.SetActive(true);

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, GameObject.[FindWithTag(string tag)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html) only returns active GameObjects. You cannot find an object that is disabled with this method. There are a few solutions:

1. Set the GameObject reference to public or add the [SerializeField] attribute, allowing you to configure it in the editor.
2. Start the GameObject as active and cache a reference to it before it becomes inactive. (in the awake method, or elsewhere)

### Update edit for more clarification on #2:

All GameObjects run Awake() and Start() before they perform any other logic.

You could move your

```
private GameObject canvasObject;
```

to a class-level variable (instead of inside a method), and inside of the Awake() method, like this:

```
void Awake()
{
    canvasObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("Delimiter");
}
```

Now you have a cached reference to your canvasObject, so you don't need to perform a GameObject.FindWithTag every time. Now you can have this method:

```
public void TurnOnImage()
{
    canvasObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: I understood point no.1 above. However, no.2 is not understood since I am quite new to Unity. Could you please elaborate with an example. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Erik. I will try your suggestion, Meanwhile, I tried a different approach i.e. switching between the main and blank scene. In the main screen, after playing a video -  for example Video #1, I use SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Assets/Interactive360/Scenes/BlankScene.unity"); Then once in the Blank Scene, I use a timer of 5 secs and return to the Main scene. But once control is back in the Main Scene, it does not resume with playing Video #2; instead it starts from the beginning. Is there any way to resume from where the Blank Screen is loaded?

Comment: Since each scene loads "fres", you would need to store data outside the scope of the scene to do this. I recommend using [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) to store short-term data that needs to persist between scenes.

Comment: Thanks @Erik. I will consider your recommendation so that I can understand more.

Comment: I have tried all possible options to fade in and out between two videos playing in a sequence within the same scene. There are many solutions online that cater to fading in an out between two scenes, but I am looking for a solution within a single scene. The last approach I tried was using a Plane attached to the Camera and manipulating the value of ALPHA over a period of time which gives the fading effect. The fade works well when the scene starts and the first video starts playing. However, it does not work at all from the second video onwards. I do not understand what I am missing here.

Comment: There is not enough detail in your request here. I cannot tell if you are asking a new question, or the original question. The original question can be resolved using a manager class that is not attached to the video player as shown in my comment. If you have a new issue, please post a new question or provide more details in your comment.

Comment: I have posted my query in a separate question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57625941/how-can-i-switch-on-the-second-camera-for-few-sec-thereby-simulating-a-blank-sc