# How can I switch on the second camera for few sec (thereby simulating a blank screen) while the first camera is still on

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am running a sequence of videos inside a scene. I want to simulate a blank screen of 2 seconds in between videos. I am using two camera's, Main and Second. The Second Camera has Solid Color, Black background and Culling Mask is set to "Nothing". After the first video playback is over, I can find from logs that second camera is enabled - but the effect is not realised since I am disabling it immediately since my second video starts. How can I keep the second camera on for some time - say 2 seconds?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;


public class Play3DVideoSequenceAmbisonics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<VideoClip> videoClipList; //list of video clips
    public List<AudioClip> audioClipList; //list of audio clips
    public List<GameObject> audioSources;

    private List<VideoPlayer> videoPlayerList;
    private int videoIndex = 0; //videoIndex is 0 initially

    [SerializeField]
    private RenderTexture _renderTexture = null;

    VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
    AudioSource audioData;


    public Camera m_MainCamera;
    public Camera m_CameraTwo;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        m_MainCamera = Camera.main;
        m_MainCamera.enabled = true;
        m_CameraTwo.enabled = false;

        StartCoroutine(PlayVideo());
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    IEnumerator PlayVideo(bool firstRun = true)
    {
        if (videoClipList == null || videoClipList.Count <= 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Assign VideoClips from the Editor");
            yield break;
        }

        //Init videoPlayerList first time this function is called
        if (firstRun)
        {
            videoPlayerList = new List<VideoPlayer>();

            for (int i = 0; i < videoClipList.Count; i++)
            {

                //Create new Object to hold the Video and the sound then make it a child of this object
                GameObject vidHolder = new GameObject("VP" + i);
                audioSources.Add(GameObject.Find("VP" + i));

                vidHolder.transform.SetParent(transform);

                //Add VideoPlayer to the GameObject
                videoPlayer = vidHolder.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>();
                videoPlayerList.Add(videoPlayer);

                //Add AudioSource to  the GameObject
                audioData = vidHolder.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

                //Enable Play on Awake for both Video and Audio
                videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;
                audioData.playOnAwake = false;

                videoPlayer.renderMode = VideoRenderMode.RenderTexture;

                //We want to play from video clip not from url
                videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;

                //Set Audio Output to AudioSource
                videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;

                //Assign the Audio from Video to AudioSource to be played
                //videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(1, true);
                //videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, audioSource);

                //Set video Clip To Play 
                videoPlayer.clip = videoClipList[i];
                audioData.clip = audioClipList[i];

                videoPlayer.targetTexture = _renderTexture;
            }
        }

        //Make sure that the NEXT VideoPlayer index is valid
        if (videoIndex >= videoPlayerList.Count)
            yield break;


        //Prepare video
        videoPlayerList[videoIndex].Prepare();

        //Wait until this video is prepared
        while (!videoPlayerList[videoIndex].isPrepared)
        {
            Debug.Log("Preparing Index: " + videoIndex);
            yield return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Done Preparing current Video Index: " + videoIndex);

        m_CameraTwo.enabled = false;
        Debug.Log("The current video index is:" + videoIndex);
        Debug.Log("The main camera is:" + m_MainCamera.enabled);
        Debug.Log("The second camera is:" + m_CameraTwo.enabled);

        //Play first video
        videoPlayerList[videoIndex].Play();

        audioSources[videoIndex].GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        audioSources[videoIndex].GetComponent<AudioSource>().spatialBlend = 1;
        audioSources[videoIndex].GetComponent<AudioSource>().spread = 360;


        //Wait while the current video is playing
        bool reachedHalfWay = false;
        int nextIndex = (videoIndex + 1);


        while (videoPlayerList[videoIndex].isPlaying)
        {
            Debug.Log("Playing time: " + videoPlayerList[videoIndex].time + " INDEX: " + videoIndex);

            //(Check if we have reached half way)
            if (!reachedHalfWay && videoPlayerList[videoIndex].time >= (videoPlayerList[videoIndex].clip.length / 2))
            {
                reachedHalfWay = true; //Set to true so that we don't evaluate this again

                //Make sure that the NEXT VideoPlayer index is valid. Othereise Exit since this is the end
                if (nextIndex >= videoPlayerList.Count)
                {
                    Debug.Log("End of All Videos: " + videoIndex);
                    yield break;
                }

                //Prepare the NEXT video
                Debug.Log("Ready to Prepare NEXT Video Index: " + nextIndex);
                videoPlayerList[nextIndex].Prepare();
            }
            yield return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Done Playing current Video Index: " + videoIndex);


        //Wait until NEXT video is prepared
        while (!videoPlayerList[nextIndex].isPrepared)
        {
            Debug.Log("Preparing NEXT Video Index: " + nextIndex);
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("Done Preparing NEXT Video Index: " + videoIndex);

        m_CameraTwo.enabled = true;
        Debug.Log("The current video index is:" + videoIndex);
        Debug.Log("The main camera is:" + m_MainCamera.enabled);
        Debug.Log("The second camera is:" + m_CameraTwo.enabled);


        //Increment Video index
        videoIndex++;

         //Play next prepared video. Pass false to it so that some codes are not executed at-all
        StartCoroutine(PlayVideo(false));

    }
```

There are no error messages - but I am unable to keep the second camera on for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer variable:

```
float second_camera_timer = 0;
```

Each `Update()` you decrement it:

```
second_camera_timer -= Time.deltaTime ();
```

And when you enable your 2nd camera, set the timer to 2 seconds:

```
second_camera_timer = 2f;
```

But before disabling it, check if timer is 0:

```
if (second_camera_timer <= 0f)
{
    m_CameraTwo.enabled = false;
}
```